# How do I redirect stdout and stderr output from a Perl script to a file on Windows?

Tags: perl, testing, selenium

I tried this:

```
test1.pl >output.log 2>&1
```

but this is the result:

```
Can't dup STDOUT:  Permission denied at C:/Perl/lib/Test/Builder.pm line 1376.
Compilation failed in require at C:/Perl/lib/Test/Builder/Module.pm line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/Perl/lib/Test/Builder/Module.pm line 3.
Compilation failed in require at C:/Perl/lib/Test/More.pm line 22.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/Perl/lib/Test/More.pm line 22.
Compilation failed in require at C:/Perl/site/lib/Test/WWW/Selenium.pm line 72.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/Perl/site/lib/Test/WWW/Selenium.pm line 72.
Compilation failed in require at C:\Software\selenium-remote-control-1.0-beta-2\tests\test1.pl line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Software\selenium-remote-control-1.0-beta-2\tests\test1.pl line 5.
```

The script runs file as long as I don't try to redirect the output from the command line in any way.

Here's my script, just in case that helps.  (It's a [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) test script):

```
#!C:/perl/bin/perl.exe -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::HiRes qw(sleep);
use Test::WWW::Selenium;
use Test::More "no_plan";
use Test::Exception;

my $sel = Test::WWW::Selenium->new( host => "localhost",
                                    port => 4444,
                                    browser => "*chrome",
                                    browser_url => "http://localhost/" );
print "Start Time: " . localtime() . "\n";
for (my $count = 3000; $count > 0; $count--)
{
    print $count . " tests remaining.\n";
    $sel->open_ok("/home");
    $sel->click_ok("link=News");
    $sel->wait_for_page_to_load_ok("30000");
    $sel->click_ok("video");
    $sel->wait_for_page_to_load_ok("30000");
    $sel->click_ok("link=Sports");
    $sel->wait_for_page_to_load_ok("30000");
    $sel->click_ok("link=Movies");
    $sel->wait_for_page_to_load_ok("30000");
    $sel->click_ok("moremovies");
    $sel->wait_for_page_to_load_ok("30000");
}

print "End Time: " . localtime() . "\n";
```

Comment: This looks like a Selenium specific issue to me. Have you tried running the script WITHOUT any calls to Selenium?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is general problem with redirection in `Perl` for `Windows`.

The line that fails in `Test::More` package says:

```
open TESTOUT, ">&STDOUT" or die $!;
```

This fails when you invoke command as `test.pl > outlog.log`, as the file that you are redirecting `STDOUT` to is locked by `cmd.exe`, not by `perl.exe`. You cannot `dup()` it from `perl.exe`

You need to run:

```
perl test1.pl >output.log 2>&1
```

instead.

Comment: In general, you will always need to run `perl foo.pl` instead of just `foo.pl` for redirections to work properly -- it's not specific to this case.  Windows blargh.

Answer (score 1):

In all my test scripts I always configure  test reporting and logging options (instead of using stdout). I also ran into the very same issue of redirecting output. You can use the solution listed above mine OR you can do what I did:

```
my $res_file = "C:\\Automation\\Results\\Test_Logs\\login_test_output.txt"; 
my $err_file = "C:\\Automation\\Results\\Test_Logs\\login_error_output.txt";

open FH, ">$res_file" or die "couldn't open file: $!";

FH->autoflush(1); # Make FileHandle HOT. Set to 0 to turn autoflush off

Test::More->builder->output (*FH{IO}); # Redirect to test result file ($res_file)
Test::More->builder->failure_output ($err_file); # and test failure output file
```

Using this approach I am able to redirect stdout and stderr output from my perl scripts to a file on Windows.